# Yii2 - session_start(): Cannot find save handler 'memcached' - session startup failed

Tags: php, yii2

I am getting this error:
`session_start(): Cannot find save handler 'memcached' - session startup failed`

in config/web.php my settings are like this:
under components

```
'cache' => [
          //  'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
            'class'        => 'yii\caching\MemCache',
            'useMemcached' => true,
            'servers' => [
                [
                    'host' => '127.0.0.1',
                    'port' => 11211

                ],
            ],
```

The phpinfo shows memcache is installed correctly.
[image]

I also used below script from this link to check if memcache is working

```
<?php
if (class_exists('Memcache')) {
    $server = '127.0.0.1';
    if (!empty($_REQUEST['server'])) {
        $server = $_REQUEST['server'];
    }
    $memcache = new Memcache;
    $isMemcacheAvailable = @$memcache->connect($server);

    if ($isMemcacheAvailable) {
        $aData = $memcache->get('data');
        echo '<pre>';
        if ($aData) {
            echo '<h2>Data from Cache:</h2>';
            print_r($aData);
        } else {
            $aData = array(
                'me' => 'you',
                'us' => 'them',
            );
            echo '<h2>Fresh Data:</h2>';
            print_r($aData);
            $memcache->set('data', $aData, 0, 300);
        }
        $aData = $memcache->get('data');
        if ($aData) {
            echo '<h3>Memcache seem to be working fine!</h3>';
        } else {
            echo '<h3>Memcache DOES NOT seem to be working!</h3>';
        }
        echo '</pre>';
    }
}
if (!$isMemcacheAvailable) {
    echo 'Memcache not available';
}

?>
```

and I am getting the result

```
Fresh Data:
Array
(
    [me] => you
    [us] => them
)
Memcache seem to be working fine!
```

what I am missing here and how to fix this error.

In top of config/web.php file

```
use app\cart\storage\SessionStorage;
Yii::$container->setSingleton('app\cart\ShoppingCart');

Yii::$container->set('app\cart\storage\StorageInterface', function() {
    return new SessionStorage(Yii::$app->session, 'primary-cart');
});
```

Comment: This error is about session, while you shared configuration of cache component. These are not directly related - you need to share configuration of your session component.

Comment: Hi Rob - is it from the same `web.php`? There is nothing in the config for session in component in web.php though I am using `sessionStorage` like - updated in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually in addition to `memcache` you need to install memcached.
when I tried `apt-get install memcached`
I was getting `memcached is installed and already newest version`

but you need to install php-memcache like

`apt-get install php-memcached`
and in your phpinfo both `memcache` `memcached` should show like below image.
[image]